# Shell Script: Passing each line as an argument to another script

Tags: bash, shell

Good day.

At work i have a script that receives a number as an argument and it shows me some information related to that number as an output.

The thing is some times i receive a huge list of numbers and executing this script numerous times during the day takes a lot of my time.

I would like to know if there is a way to save all those numbers on a file and direct each line of said file to be executed by the script.

Lets say my file contains the following numbers:

```
999999999
888888888
777777777
666666666
555555555
```

and the script is executed as follows:

```
sh script.sh 55(Number) go
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try piping. For example `cat example.txt | ./script.sh`

Comment: It didn`t work, it just ask me to type a number

Comment: thanks mate, ill look into it.

Comment: BTW, when you run it yourself, do you run `55(111111)` or `55111111`? I answered for the former, but if what you *really* want is the latter, then you'd want to take the parenthesis out of my answer, and use `"55${line}"` instead of `"55(${line})"`.

Comment: (whereas the other answer assumed the latter, so if you want the parens to be literal, you'd need to add them there).

Comment: By the way, you aren't doing something silly like running `var=$(whatever)`, and then running `echo $var`? Because that's one of the best ways to make all your newlines disappear. (`echo "$var"` is needed to prevent your variable from being split on whitespace and having each word treated as a glob before being passed to `echo`).

Comment: Edited. Again, please try to write your questions to be more unambiguously clear in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish that is using `xargs`, for example:

```
xargs -I{} sh script.sh 55{} go < numbers.txt
```

This assumes that you put your numbers in a file named `numbers.txt`.
For each line in the file, the `{}` in `sh script.sh 55{} go` will be replaced with the value in the line.

For example:

```
xargs -I{} echo number is: {} < input
```

Given your sample input, the above will produce:

> ```
> number is: 999999999
> number is: 888888888
> number is: 777777777
> number is: 666666666
> number is: 555555555
> ```

Comment: Interesting. If this worked, I wonder if the original (pre-FD-3) version of mine would have been better-behaved -- I can't think of any other difference in how their runtime behavior presents to the child process running the script.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your inputs are in `input.txt`, a simple `while read` loop will do:

```
while read -r line <&3; do
  sh script.sh "55${line}" go
done 3<input.txt
```

See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for discussion of this technique.

---

A few notes:

- `sh script.sh` is actually very poor form: It ignores the shebang line in that script, such that it can no longer specify its own interpreter. It's much better to run `./script.sh` after making your script executable; that way if it has `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/usr/bin/ksh` or any other shebang that will be honored, so you don't risk causing your script to fail by running it with a POSIX sh interpreter when it was written for a more capable shell language.
- The `3<input.txt` puts the input file on descriptor 3, rather than the default `<input.txt` redirection of using stdin; using an alternate file descriptor number ensures that your script can read from the user (prompting from stdin), if it wants to.

Comment: This one worked but for some reason the output is no formatted properly. When executing the script normally all information about the number is shown is separated lines. With this all the information is show in the same line

Comment: I can't help with that without seeing the script.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man, ...that said, was this the first revision (using stdin), or the current one (using FD 3) where you observed that? If it checks whether stdin is a TTY to decide whether to format output for human consumption, that could explain the difference.

Comment: Using the current one.

Comment: Then we're definitely in can't-help-without-a-reproducer space. (This is part of why it's important, when asking a question, to include everything necessary to tell if an answer is correct *in the question itself*).

Comment: I know but i don`t think i can`t show much about the script because it isn`t mine and it is also work related, so some stuff on i can`t show anything on it without getting fired.

Comment: That's one of the reasons why this site [asks you to build a **M**inimal, **C**omplete, **V**erifiable **E**xample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question about code -- generating only the smallest amount of code needed to demonstrate your problem means you aren't including literal content owned by someone else and thus violating confidentiality, while still making sure your answers include everything needed for someone to test their answers. See also the (closely related) http://sscce.org/, describing the same practice with slightly different terminology.

Comment: BTW, backticks are used to delimit code formatting here. Use forward quotes for contractions like `don't`.

Comment: Well, sorry about that mate.